# using apache-storm-2.2.1 cluster run topologies,problem?

Tags: apache-storm

Run 3 Topologies On Storm Clusters,Through storm list command line ,show me 3 topologies and the state all ACTIVE ,But In /home/storm/data/supervisor/stormdist/  Dir only 2 topologies, One Of them Not Run?

Comment: Have you checked the `nimbus.log`? And what is the content in `/supervisor/stormdist/`?

Comment: nimbus.log records normal run information,   the stormdist dir list my topology instance；Is it possible，the memory size not enough？

Comment: In my case, supervisor/stormdist is empty, although I ran multiple queries. So I would rely more on the storm list command...